# flex datagrid: elemenst do not refresh inside : what do be done?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I have a  compoonent inside flex4.5 in 3 columns

When I add some elements, soemtimes these one of these elements just got invisible: 
when I resize the browser, it appears again.

There is no rule: it happens randomly and element is always avaible: I tried with referesh, update but this do not help.

ANy idea on why this happens and how to solve that bug ?

```
                <mx:DataGrid id="rowcolordatagrid1" left="10" right="10" top="49" variableRowHeight="true" 
                                         bottom="58" borderColor="#CCCCCC" color="#5A5A5A" dataProvider="{questions_dp}" symbolColor="#CCCCCC">
                <mx:columns>                        
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="data" headerText="{xml.questions}" itemRenderer="QuestionRenderer" sortable="false"/>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn width="150" headerText="{xml.action}" itemRenderer="ActionRenderer" sortable="false"/>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="priority" headerText="{xml.priority}" itemRenderer="PriorityRenderer" width="100"  />
                </mx:columns>
            </mx:DataGrid>
```

of course I tried questions_dp.refresh();

[image: lines have diseappeared !]

But when I resize or minimize my browsers, these blank lines appear again !
These lines happens sometimes : I would say 20% of chance some rows are invisible.

reagrds

Comment: I think you need to rework your question to be more specific.  You have what type of component in Flex 4.5?  A MX DataGrid?  A Spark DataGrid?  Or something else?  You are adding elements to what?   What elements go invisible when you resize the browser?    What type of elements are you discussing?  Rows on a DataGrid?  New items to a dataProvider?  You tried to refresh what?  And how?  You trued to update what?  And how?  Can you provide sample code demonstrating your problem? Possibly with a screenshot?

Comment: I provided screenshot and code.
Regards

Comment: Might have something to do with the renderers?

Comment: Be sure to answer the rest of my questions.  Also, you may tell us when you tried to do questions_dp.refresh(); what the reason for it was.  Also add some context to your screenshots, such as what is [or is not] there and what shouldn't be [or should be]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is because your item render.

remove 'QuestionRenderer' and try again.

if it is OK for the first column, then check all your render class:
 Did you forgot to call super.method(..) with in every override metod in you render class?